# How to move your focus out of the text?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I've got a PDF open in Acrobat.

I like to scroll the "standard" way, where I can press the arrow key up to go up by a line or two, and the arrow key down for the opposite.

But sometimes I accidentally click the text, and then suddenly the arrow keys control moving the cursor around inside the page instead, so I have to hold it down and move the cursor all the way to the bottom of the page before it'll start scrolling the page down, and then all the way back up if I want to go up again.

I can't find any way to move focus out of the text once I've clicked it. I actually have to close Acrobat and reopen the PDF. It's kind of amazing.

Solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch your tool from the **Select Tool** to the **Hand Tool**.  While the Hand Tool is really meant for panning around on a page, it will remove the cursor from the page text, allowing you to use the arrow keys for page navigation again.

The easiest way to activate the Hand Tool is to right-click the document and select it from the context menu.  Depending on what version of Adobe you are using, there may be a menu button to change them as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try 'tab', that should change the focus.

Comment: Absolutely no effect whatsoever. Sorry! My tests were thorough-- this is a surprisingly difficult little bug.